# Pass UI in parameter in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have an windows ui in a Qt project and I want pass this ui in parameter to another function, like that:

```
ConfWindows::ConfWindows(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::ConfWindows)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->add_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(add_elem(ui->name_edit)));
}

void        add_elem(QLabel test)
{
    qDebug() << test.text();
}
```

But I get an error when I try to do that:

```
'QLabel::QLabel(const QLabel&)' is private
 Q_DISABLE_COPY(QLabel)
```

It's impossible to pass an ui element in parameters ?

Thank for you help.

Comment: Pass by `const&`?

Comment: Like this ?

    `void        add_elem(QLabel const& test)
    {
        qDebug() << test.text();
    }`

I got this error :

    `undefined reference to ConfWindows::add_elem(QLabel const&)`

But, add_elem is a slot so he don't need the "ConfWindows::" before right ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SLOT(add_elem(QLabel)));` in the first place? Also, is copying is disabled, pass by const reference.

Comment: @Sonny if you change it in the header you also have to change it in the cpp file.

Comment: You cannot pass a QLineEdit into a slot which needs a QLabel. You should research on how to get the text out of a line edit and set the text of a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not a good practice to pass your ui as a parameter.
Secondly you should have can not have more parameters in a slot's function prototype than your signal has.

I should do it like this:
I would make add_elem function, a member function of `ConfWindows` class, in order to have access to ui inside it's body and get the text of the label.

```
ConfWindows::ConfWindows(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::ConfWindows) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->add_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(add_elem()));
}

void ConfWindows::add_elem() {
    QString text = ui->label->text();
    qDebug() << test.text();
}
```